# Utility like NPAPI Spy for ACTIVEX?

Tags: plugins, activex, npapi

just wondering if there is any open source implementation for an ActiveX web plugins similar in functionality to the one implemented by NPAPI Spy utility available at:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/tools/spy/

Thanks,
 
Giovanni

Comment: NPAPI spy code can be found here: http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/tools/spy/
basically allows to log when a plugin gets invoked by the browser and viceversa, allowing still to use the original plugin.

Comment: Is there a tool like this for Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no such utility exists, however you could probably use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) or [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find most of what you need.  If you could give us a more specific idea of what problem you're trying to solve, we may be able to help you better with another solution.

Comment: Hi Taxilian,

The goal i'm trying to achieve is to create a plugin that front-end another existing plugin, in particular i want to create a plugin for the windows media player plugin such that mine will be called by firefox/internet explorer before the actual windows media player plugin. Once my plugin gets called, i will do some check on the URL of the media file we want to play and eventually rewrite it. Once the check is done i want to invoke the original plugin. 
Thanks

Comment: This can be done, though it's tricky.  Basically, you'll need to instantiate your activex control and then instantiate the windows media player activex control inside it.  Then you can use the same API calls that the browser would to proxy calls from the browser to the internal plugin.  If you do it right, it will be transparent.  I've done it before, but it took some real work.  If you are willing to make it a partial framework that can be contributed to an open source project, I've been wanting to add that feature to FireBreath and I could probably help you get started, at least.